Warning in perl useless use of private variable in void context
I have a script that take a string and puts a '.html' at the end of a string.
If the string already has a '.hmtl" i want to strip it, and then add the html later
It works ok but I get a warning and dont understand the warning.
so if i run the script withthe string foo_foo.html, I don't want the result to be foo_foo.html.html, I put in the if statement
if ($input =~ s/\.html$//)

so it strips the 'dot html' from the string
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Check if a string is provided as an argument
if (@ARGV != 1) {
    die "Usage: $0 'string'\n";
}

# Get the input string from the command line arguments
my $input = $ARGV[0];

if ($input =~ s/\.html$//) {
        $input ;
}


# Convert all characters to lowercase
$input = lc($input);

# Replace spaces with underscores
$input =~ s/ /_/g;

# Print the modified string
print "<!--- \"$input.html\" -->\n";
print "     \n";
print "     \n";
print "$input.html"

I get this warning
 Useless use of private variable in void context at 
./perl_make_html_string_cut_html.pl line 14.

The script works ok  - just the warning is bothering me.

It's a one-liner: perl -ple's/^(.*?)(\.html)?$/lc($1)=~s# #_#gr . ".html"/ie' 

It is this part:
if ($input =~ s/\.html$//) {
        $input ;   # <----- error line
}

Perhaps you meant to put a print statement there? As of now it is just a variable in void context, like the error says.
You could just do:
$input =~ s/\.html$//;

And skip the if-clause. I would perhaps add /i flag to remove text regardless of case.
If you have a text editor that shows line numbers, you can just see which line is reporting the error yourself.

Yes that is the line - NO i do no want too put a print statement there  - if the string ends in a "dot html", I want the '.html" stripped off. The script does what I want I just hate the warning.

I know it does what you want. If you don't want the warning, don't put the line with just a variable in void context. Are you not understanding what is going on?

If you need more explanation, I can give it, but you have to tell me. :)

@capser You left out the useless if in the following $input =~ s/ /_/g; line. Just do the same thing with the first substitution.

I took out the if statement and it works with out warning. I guess i thought i needed the if clause for just that situation - when I input a string already ending in an dot html.

@capser The if is implied in the regex. If the string has ".html", it will be removed.

What do you think you get from this code:
if ($input =~ s/\.html$//) {
        $input ;
}

That you don't get from just:
$input =~ s/\.html$//;

Update: Fair point TLP. So the answer is - replace
if ($input =~ s/\.html$//) {
        $input ;
}

with:
$input =~ s/\.html$//;


That's more of a comment than an answer. :)
